# Could not initialize class weblogic.utils.LocatorUtilities$Locator

Tags: java, liferay, weblogic, jndi

I´m trying to make a remote call from `Liferay` to a `EJB` deployed in a `Weblogic Server 12.2.1.3.0`.

I´m using  `wlthint3client.jar`, `Java jdk1.8.0_172` and `Liferay DXP`,
but it throws the next exception:

```
18:11:31,101 ERROR [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'][DispatcherPortlet:573] Could not complete request
javax.portlet.PortletException: Error occured during request processing: Could not initialize class weblogic.utils.LocatorUtilities$Locator
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doActionService(DispatcherPortlet.java:692)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:533)
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processAction(FrameworkPortlet.java:473)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletExceptionAdapter.service(ServletExceptionAdapter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:50)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:191)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:191)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:99)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.utils.LocatorUtilities$Locator
    at weblogic.utils.LocatorUtilities.getService(LocatorUtilities.java:37)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:124)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at mx.com.procesar.esar.portal.imprimecurp.controller.impl.ImprimeCurpControllerImpl.executeImprimeCurpResponse(ImprimeCurpControllerImpl.java:169)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

I think I need some dependencies but I can figure out what they are, Do you have any idea about what's happening here?

Thank you so much for reading

Comment: *I think I need some dependencies* - can you post the dependencies that you have, e.g. how do you build your project, how do you deploy (OSGi-bundle or WAR style portlet)? DXP 7.0? 7.1?

Comment: Hello Olaf, thanks for your help, I'm using DXP 7.0, it's a WAR style portlet (Spring MVC Portlet), my portal is deployed on a Weblogic Server 12.2.1.3.0, the EJB is deployed  on another server (Wblogic 10), the dependencies that I'm using for creating the context are wlthint3client.jar, weblogic.jar and wljmsclient.jar

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and it was caused by a hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar added in my classpath.
You can resolve this by making sure that the wlthint3client dependency is loaded before hk2-locator.

By the way, I'm not sure to understand why you have added the wlthint3client.jar to your WAR file as it is deployed on a WLS.
The Thinclient is designed to run outside of a Weblogic container, like the Oracle documentation describes it :

`The Thin T3 client can be used in standalone applications, and is also designed for applications running on foreign (non-WebLogic) servers. One common use case is integration with WebLogic JMS destinations.`

[Oracle WLS documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/saclt/wlthint3client.html)